# REST API Creation of Multiple Resources

Tags: java, api, swagger, api-design, openapi

I am currently working with an API where a POST request may create multiple resources, depending on the resource being passed. To give you an example, I have a `Reservation` resource, and two child resources, `Ancillary` and `SpecialRequest`. A reservation is uniquely identified by an alphanumeric string of 6 characters, and an `Ancillary` is identified by a unique ID within the reservation (i.e. ancillary IDs are only known to the parent reservation).

So, to create an Ancillary, my API endpoint looks like this:

`POST /reservations/{reservationId}/ancillaries/`

Usually REST states that the resource being created (`Ancillary` in this case) is the resource that should be returned. However, my use-case is somewhat more complicated than that, since the reservation system which my API is interfacing with is legacy, and is somewhat unpredictable.

There are certain ancillaries (bundles) which actually create *multiple* ancillaries. For example, an ancillary might be a package of two other ancillaries, which costs less than if you had to purchase the other two ancillaries. Moreover, an ancillary might also be linked automatically to a `SpecialRequest`.

I'm wondering what my options are ... so far I've come up with the following:

1. Return the entire `Reservation`, which is sure to include all sub resources which were created and/or modified as a result of the Ancillary creation. This is the "safest" option, but in doing so I wouldn't be able to tell the user which `Ancillary`s were created.
2. Return only the `Ancillary` which was created, however this approach is likely make my API less usable since the API user is extremely likely to perform a `GET /reservations/{reservationId}`
3. Return a `Ancillary[]` regardless of the ancillary type, although this still leaves out the link between the `Ancillary` and the `SpecialRequest`.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts and input

Comment: Consider using JSON:API or a similar approach where you have an `included` option.

Comment: what about returning the result of the operation, instead of thiking about which object to return. e.g: a response that describes : (1) The main ancillary created, (2) a list of other Ancillaries & SpecialRequest created